# django DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS not working

Tags: django

in my settings.py settings, I have

```
from django.conf.global_settings import DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p',)
```

But when I enter the date `2015-10-23 01:48 pm` in my form that takes date time I get `Enter a valid date/time.`.

The model is `date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)`.

How can make the model take the format `2015-10-23 01:48 pm`?

Comment: What is `base.py`?  Did you mean to say `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you have set `USE_L10N` to `True` in your settings. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) for `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`:

> When `USE_L10N` is True, the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.

i.e., your carefully constructed setting will be ignored :).

Also, note that depending on your locale, `%p` expects different values - e.g., for `en_US` it expects capitalised `AM` and `PM`.