# Django: DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS with USE_L10N?

Tags: django, django-forms

It is documented that when USE_L10N is True, that DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS are ignored. And this was well explained here:

[django DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177707/django-datetime-input-formats-not-working)

But I am left wondering then, if USE_L10N is True, then how does one add to the legal datetime formats? I know DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS is ignored, great, but what isn't? Ignored that is. And can one do the equivalent in L10N terms?